# How to read value from SimpleXMLElement by using PHP 7.0

Tags: php

I have an XML with product. I have a problem with read values witch has a "-" in name because this method dosent work:

```
$productHurtoID = $product->kod-kreskowy->__toString();
```

Below You have $product variable:

```
SimpleXMLElement object {
  nazwa => SimpleXMLElement object
  kod-katalogowy => (string) K0428
  kod-kreskowy => (string) 0027084373370
}
```

Thanks for help. Kind regards

Comment: properties shouldn't be hyphenated, they should be camelCase

Comment: I don't understand. Could you use another words ? to describe problem ?

Comment: object properties should be camelCase -> so, `kod-katalogowy` should be `kodKatalogowy`, then you call it like `$obj->kodKatalogowy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access your dynamically created properties via

```
$productHurtoID = $product->{'kod-kreskowy'}->__toString();
```

A different approach would be to pre-process your XML input and replace hyphens with camelCase. But depending on your use-case, this might not be possible.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for getting values with `-` (hyphen) in key.

```
$productHurtoID = $product->nazwa->{'kod-kreskowy'}->__toString();
```